# Why does "if($_SESSION['count'] >= 3" giving me error?

Tags: php, undefined

This php line

```
<?php if($_SESSION['count'] >= 3)?>
```

of code gives me the following error message

> Notice: Undefined index: count in C:\xampp\htdocs\vb\Step4.php on line
>   451       Number of Room/s

Comment: You are confusing with [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function instead of count key

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the existence of the `count` index before trying to use it - so:

```
<?php
    if( !empty( $_SESSION['count'] ) && intval( $_SESSION['count'] ) >= 3 ){/* do something */}
?>
```

You could use `isset` to test that the index has been defined but `empty` does that and also checks that whatever value is held does is not empty and not equate to false.

Answer (score 0):

Session with name 'count' is not set.
i.e. The array $_SESSION does not any key with name 'count'.

Also, it is a NOTICE ( information ) not an ERROR.

Comment: so where do I set the 'count'

Comment: If you are expecting 'count' in $_SESSION then ideally you should have set 'count' in session using `$_SESSION['count'] = 3;` before calling `if($_SESSION['count'] >= 3)`

Please see [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) for examples.